# Convert String html to array object type

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I have string content html example:

`Yjgbhg <img id="image1" src="https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5940_image-0878eae8-e316-46fc-a776-b3d22e292c55.jpg">Huyju  <video src="https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5824_video.mp4" id="video1" onclick="blurEditor();" onplay="blurEditor();" controls=""></video>`

I want pass string to object same

```
[
  {
    type: "text",
    value: "Yjgbhg"
  },
  {
    type: "img",
    value: "https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5940_image-0878eae8-e316-46fc-a776-b3d22e292c55.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    value: "Huyju"
  },
  {
    type: "text",
    value: "https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5824_video.mp4"
  },

]
```

I try used

```js
var regexp = /<img[^>]*src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\/>/g;
        console.log(regexp.exec( strHtml ));
        while ( m = regexp.exec( text ) ) {
            urls.push( m[0] );
        }
var regexp = /<video[^>]*src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*\/>/img;
        while ( m = regexp.exec( text ) ) {
            urls.push( m[0] );
        }
        
        console.log(urls);
```

to get img and video but it return array null.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be a lot easier to use `DOMParser`:

```js
const input = `Yjgbhg <img id="image1" src="https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5940_image-0878eae8-e316-46fc-a776-b3d22e292c55.jpg">Huyju  <video src="https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5824_video.mp4" id="video1" onclick="blurEditor();" onplay="blurEditor();" controls=""></video>`;
const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, 'text/html');
const text1 = parser.body.childNodes[0].textContent.trim();
const img = parser.body.children[0].src;
const text2 = parser.body.childNodes[2].textContent.trim();
const video = parser.body.children[1].src;
console.log([text1, img, text2, video]);
```

Comment: I try `import {DOMParser} from 'react-native'` but it show `_reactNative.DOMParser is not a constructor`

Comment: It's a property of `window`, not a property of `reactNative`, as you can see in the snippet

Comment: if your code run it will true will only string, don't working with other case

Comment: What other case? Your question only says `I have string`

Comment: I'm sorry, I editted my question to example string, my bad

Comment: If what you have is HTML rather than a string, then you can select the elements directly instead, like with `document.body.childNodes[0].textContent`

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it to a DOM tree, and then map the nodes of the DOM tree to objects.

In the code below assume that you only have text nodes and element nodes for which you want to retrieve the `src` property. If you have others, you'll have to add some logic to the mapping.

```
const htmlToObject = (html) => {
  const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  const object = Array.from(dom.body.childNodes).reduce((a, v) => {
    switch(v.nodeType) {
      case 1: // element node
        a.push({type: v.tagName.toLowerCase(), value: v.src});
        break;
      case 3: // text node
        a.push({type: 'text', value: v.textContent.trim()});
        break;
    }

    return a;
  }, []);

  return object;
}
```

**Full snippet:**

```js
const htmlToObject = (html) => {
  const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  const object = Array.from(dom.body.childNodes).reduce((a, v) => {
    switch(v.nodeType) {
      case 1:
        a.push({type: v.tagName.toLowerCase(), value: v.src});
        break;
      case 3:
        a.push({type: 'text', value: v.textContent.trim()});
        break;
    }
    
    return a;
  }, []);
  
  return object;
}

const html = 'Yjgbhg <img id="image1" src="https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5940_image-0878eae8-e316-46fc-a776-b3d22e292c55.jpg">Huyju  <video src="https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5824_video.mp4" id="video1" onclick="blurEditor();" onplay="blurEditor();" controls=""></video>';

console.log(htmlToObject(html));
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "type": "text",
    "value": "Yjgbhg"
  },
  {
    "type": "img",
    "value": "https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5940_image-0878eae8-e316-46fc-a776-b3d22e292c55.jpg"
  },
  {
    "type": "text",
    "value": "Huyju"
  },
  {
    "type": "video",
    "value": "https://dzlvqfm687ile.cloudfront.net/5824_video.mp4"
  }
]
```

Comment: It show `DOMParser is not defined` how I can import it? sorry i'm android developer show I don't know more JS and RN

Comment: *It* show `DOMParser is not defined`. What is *it*?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ndskyt?file=Hello.js here is my code. Can you check it?

Comment: So you just need to add a DOMParser, for example using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-parser

Comment: I installed DOMParser and it working but when I `console.log(dom.body.childNodes)` it return `undefined`, it is `dom.childNodes` and when `console.log(Array.from(parsed.childNodes))`
it show array 3 item but can't see src in array, I can see namespaceURI but value of node is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` both tag video and img